# Python - nested lists vs multiple dictionaries for bicycle gear calculator

Tags: python, list, dictionary

this is my first Stack Overflow question so if this is not optimal please let me know, I appreciate the feedback.

I am studying Computer Science and for my final project I'm making a bicycle gear calculator. I want there to be 3 drop down menus (Brand and 1x or 2x, Crank, Cassette), the first menu (Brand) should auto-populate the next 2 menus (Crank and Cassette). For example, in the first menu there should be Shimano 1x and Shimano 2x, if you select Shimano 1x then the crank drop down menu should be [53, 39], [52, 36], [50, 34], and Cassette should be [11, 28], [11, 32], [11, 36]. If you select Shimano 2x the Crank Menu should be 46, 36, 34, (yes sometimes the Crank is a series of single entries and sometimes it is a series of pairs) and the cassette should be [11, 36], [11, 534]. In the finished version there will be many more options, this is just an example.

Philosophically what is the best way to structure this data? Should I make each thing a list and then call it somehow? Should I make 1 giant dictionary that has everything correctly nested? And if I do that can someone point me in the correct direction to figure out the nesting syntax? Thank you so much and I hope this appropriate. Also when the final 2 drop downs are selected I need a function to call them and do a calculation with the integers, but I think once it is called correctly I know how to do the math and output it. I am doing the drop downs with tKinter.

Here is my code, please don't judge me, I am really struggling and trying my best to make sense of this :( And yes the shimano 1x / shimano 2x example from above is slightly different below, i am really trying to get total_gear_options_dict to work with the drop downs, but so far i was just using brand_options to test and make sure the drop down works (it does).

```
#HOW DO I NEST THIS? IS THIS EVEN CLOSE TO CORRECT? IT SAYS LINE 37 : IS WRONG
total_gear_options_dict = {
    ['shimano2xroad': 
        {'chainring': {
            [53, 39],
            [52, 36],
            [50,34]},
            }
        'cassette': {
            [11, 23],
            [11, 25],
            [11, 28],
            [11, 32],
            [11, 34],
            }
    ]
    ['shimano1xgravel':
        'Chainring':
            [46, 36, 34],
        'Cassette': {
            [11, 36],
            [11,42]
            }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post only the part of your code with the problem, so we can zero in on it.

Comment: This would be a great question for the codereview community, if you can't narrow it down

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, i just narrowed it down to exactly the part in question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a reasonable way to represent your data.  In general you may find pretending that python is more typed (no mixed values in dicts/lists) will simplify your algorithms, so lets tweak your values slightly to do that:

```
gear_options :: {brand_name: brand_info, ...}
brand_info :: {"chainring": crank_entries, "cassette": crank_entries}
crank_entry :: [crank_pair] | [crank_single]
```

The pair/single representation can be many things, but I suspect you can make them both the same or similar types, lets go with always-tuples, but two different lengths:

```
crank_pair :: (int, int)
crank_item :: (int,)
```

For your example above, you would then use

```
gear_options = {  # gear_options
  "Shimano Road 2x": { # brand_info
    "chainring": [  # crank_entries ([crank_pair])
      (53, 39),  # crank_pair
      (52, 36),  # crank_pair
      (50, 34),  # crank_pair
    ],
    "cassette": [  # crank_entries ([crank_pair])
      [11, 23],
      [11, 25],  # real code won't typically have comment-types
      [11, 28],  # mentioned beyond the very top level
      [11, 32],
      [11, 34],
    ],
  },
  ...
}
```

While making this conversion I noticed you had several syntax errors, missing commas, using `[]` instead of `{}`, using `{}` as a set instead of a list (no colons, e.g. `{1,2}` vs `[1,2]` vs `{1:2}`).  Keeping your data well structured will solve a lot of problems immediately.

Note that from the above you no longer need a separate variable to sync up with your dropdown list, that is simply `gear_options.keys()`, though you may want to make `"chainring"` and `"cassette"` constants.

Comment: thank you for your reply Cireo, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The correct code ended up being as follows, thank you for all your input! Very close to what was posted by Cireo, except I went with 'chainring': { with the curly brace instead of a list, not sure if it would work either way but it definitely correctly works as posted below. You could do the tuples as Cireo posted for the combos (53, 39), that is technically preferred I suppose, but I went with lists only because it was easier to type and functions identical.

```
gearset = {
'Shimano 2x Road': {
    'chainring': {
        '53-39': [53, 39],
        '52-36': [52, 36],
        '50-34': [50, 34]
        },
    'cassette': {
        '11-34': [11, 34],
        '11-32': [11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 25, 28, 32],
        '11-28': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 28]
        }
    },
'Shimano 1x Gravel': {
    'chainring': {
        '46': [46],
        '36': [36],
        '34': [34]},
    'cassette': {
        '11-36': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 36],
        '11-42': [11, 14, 15, 19, 42]
        }
    },
'SRAM 2x Road': {
    'chainring': {
        '53-39': [53, 39],
        '52-36': [52, 36],
        '50-34': [50, 34]
        },
    'cassette': {
        '11-28': [11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28],
        '11-32': [11, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 30, 32],
        '11-36': [11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 22, 25, 28, 32, 36]
        }
    },
'SRAM 1x Gravel': {
    'chainring': {
        '36': [36],
        '40': [40],
        '42': [42]
        },
    'cassette': {
        '10-26': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 21, 23, 26],  # range %260
        '10-28': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 21, 24, 28],  # range %280
        '10-33': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21, 24, 28, 33], # range %330
        '10-36': [10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 24, 28, 32, 36], # range %360
        '10-42': [10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 21, 24, 28, 32, 36, 42],
        '10-50': [10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 21, 24, 28, 32, 36, 42, 50]
        }
},
'Rotor 1x': {
    'chainring': {
        '54': [54],
        '52': [52],
        '50': [50],
        '48': [48],
        '46': [46],
        '44': [44],
        '42': [42],
        '40': [40],
        '38': [38]
    },
    'cassette': {
        '10-36': [10, 36],
        '10-39': [10, 39],
        '10-46': [10, 46],
        '11-36': [11, 36],
        '11-39': [11, 39],
        '11-46': [11, 46],
        '11-52': [11, 52]
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Glad it helped.  I guess you ended up solving your pair issue by using `##-##` in the key?  Feel free to mark as "accepted" if it answered your question